# Not able to configure vertex attributes correctly in Opengl 2.x

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl

Problem: **I can't make the triangle to appear. I'm not able to set up the vertex attributes correctly only by using OpenGL 2.0**

Result of a run of the code: **Red window 600*800 without a triangle.**

Objective: I try to:

- associate the position to attribute array 0,  `float` x 2 (for a
  start)
- associate the color to attribute array 1,  `int` x 3
- indexed vertices.

Java code:

```java
package prot20;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_FALSE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_TRUE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwCreateWindow;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwDefaultWindowHints;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwGetPrimaryMonitor;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwInit;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwPollEvents;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwShowWindow;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwSwapInterval;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWindowHint;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwWindowShouldClose;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_FLOAT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TRIANGLES;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClear;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glClearColor;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glDrawElements;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnableClientState;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glGetString;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glOrtho;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glViewport;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glUseProgram;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLCapabilities;

public class prot20_2 {
    private long window;
    private int width = 800;
    private int height = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new prot20_2();
    }

    public prot20_2() {

        if (!glfwInit()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        glfwDefaultWindowHints();
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW_TRUE);

        long monitor = glfwGetPrimaryMonitor();

        window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "Window20", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            throw new AssertionError("Failed to create window");
        }

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSwapInterval(0);
        glfwShowWindow(window);

        GLCapabilities c = GL.createCapabilities();

        System.out.println(c.OpenGL20);
        System.out.println(glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));

        int program = util.createProgram(prot20_2.getSimpleVertexShaderCode(), prot20_2.getSimpleFragmentShaderCode());


        float[] vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
        int[] color = { 0, 128, 128, 128, 0, 128, 128, 128, 0 };
        int[] indices = { 0, 1, 2 };

        FloatBuffer vb = this.toBuffer(vertices);
        IntBuffer ib = this.toBuffer(indices);
        IntBuffer cb = this.toBuffer(color);

        int vbo = glGenBuffers();
        int ibo = glGenBuffers();
        int cbo = glGenBuffers();

        // Position
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position");
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Color
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_INT, false, 0, 0);
        glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "color");
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // indices
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glUseProgram(program);

        while (glfwWindowShouldClose(this.window) == false) {
            glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

            float aspect = (float) width / height;
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1);

            // glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);

            glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0L);

            glfwSwapBuffers(this.window);
            glfwPollEvents();

        }
        glDeleteBuffers(vbo);

    }

    private FloatBuffer toBuffer(float[] f) {
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(f.length);
        buffer.put(f);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }

    private IntBuffer toBuffer(int[] i) {
        IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(i.length);
        buffer.put(i);
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }
    public static String getSimpleFragmentShaderCode() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("uniform vec3 color;\n");
        sb.append("void main(void) {\n");
        sb.append("  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0);");
        sb.append("}\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String getSimpleVertexShaderCode() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("uniform vec2 position;\n");
        sb.append("void main(void) {\n");
        sb.append("  gl_Position = vec4(position.xy,0.0,0.0);\n");
        sb.append("}\n");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

I have looked for documentation and examples, but either I find trivial examples without attributes, color, indices or shaders, or I find complex code using opengl 3+. I find it hard to locate a good example covering: opengl 2.1 including shader,index,attribute,color and texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to draw a triangle with a color associated to each vertex coordinate then you need a vertex shader with 2 attributes. One for the vertex coordinate and one for the color. The color attribute has to be passed from the [Vertex Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Shader) to the [Fragment Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fragment_Shader), by a `varying` variable.
Note, `attribute` and `varying` are deprecated but have to be used in GLSL version 1.10, which corresponds to OpenGL version 2.0. In "moder" OpenGL the [Type Qualifiers (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)) `in` and `out` are used:

*Vertex shader*

```c
#version 110

attribute vec2 in_pos;
attribute vec3 in_col;  

varying vec3 v_volor;

void main()
{
    v_color = in_col;
    gl_Position = vec4(in_pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

*Fragment shader*

```c
varying vec3 v_color;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, 1.0);
}
```

After the program is linked you have to get the attribute indices of `in_pos` and `in_col` by [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetAttribLocation.xhtml):

```java
int attr_pos = glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_pos");
int attr_col = glGetAttribLocation(program, "in_col");
```

If you wat to set the attribute indices by [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) the this would have to be done, before the program is linked by [`glLinkProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glLinkProgram.xhtml), because this is an information which is processed in the link process.

The color channels in [OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Shading_Language) have to be in the range [0.0, 1.0] where *RGB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)* is completely black and *RGB(1.0, 1.0, 1.0)* is white. So the color attributes have to be floating point values:

```java
float[] vertices = { -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };
float[] color    = { 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0 };
int[]   indices  = { 0, 1, 2 };

FloatBuffer vb = this.toBuffer(vertices);
FloatBuffer cb = this.toBuffer(color);
IntBuffer   ib = this.toBuffer(indices);
```

Generate the array buffers and the index buffer:

```java
int vbo = glGenBuffers();
int cbo = glGenBuffers();
int ibo = glGenBuffers();

// Position
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Color
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cb, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// indices
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ib, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Specify the arrays of generic vertex attribute data:

```java
// Position
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_pos);
glVertexAttribPointer(attr_pos, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

// Color
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(attr_col);
glVertexAttribPointer(attr_col, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

For drawing the object the program object has to installed by [`glUseProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glUseProgram.xhtml) and the element buffer has to be bound:

```java
glUseProgram(program);

while (glfwWindowShouldClose(this.window) == false) {

    // ....

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0L);

    // .....
}
```

---

Note, fixed-function attributes (`glVertexPointer`, ...), client capabilities (`glEnableClientState`/ `glDisableClientState`) and the fixed function matrix stack (`glMatrixMode`, `glLoadIdentity`, ...) have no effect, when a shader program like this is used.

If you want to use matrix transformations, then you have to use [Uniform](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) variables of type `mat4` and to setup your own projection, view and model matrices - e.g by [Matrix4f](http://legacy.lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/util/vector/Matrix4f.html) library.

Comment: Thank you very much. :-) You explained this in a very clean and understandable way. In some time I might return with some silly question on how to swap color with textures, but it'll have to survive the test of time, maybe I'll find it out my self with this new understanding.

Comment: @Tormod This is a broad task. Start at reading [The Quad textured](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/wiki/The_Quad_textured.html).